# Problem with cannot read property of undefined while reducing list of products

Tags: javascript, reduce

at first sorry for Polish words in the list, but I wouldn't be able to change it.
I want to reduce the list of products to make it as a list of objects, where they key would be "typ" (category). It is working if a product has only one category (typ), but it doesn't want to compile when I give two categories to a product.
The weird thing is that I copied my code from a different exercise where I had to do the same with the books' list, and it was working, now it says that "cannot read property of undefined".
Could you help me why?

A piece of products' list:

```
const listaZakupow = [{
    produkt: "chleb",
    typ: "pieczywo",
    ilosc: 2,
    cena: 3.6,
    jednostka: "sztuk"
},
    {
        produkt: "jabłka",
        typ: ["owoce", "slodkie"],
        ilosc: 6,
        cena: 2.5,
        jednostka: "kg"
    },
    {
        produkt: "mleko",
        typ: ["nabiał", "bialko"],
        ilosc: 3,
        cena: 2.9,
        jednostka: "litry"
    },
```

My code:

```
const produkty = listaZakupow.reduce((prev,curr) => {
    if (curr.typ instanceof Array) {
        curr.typ.reduce((prevTyp,currTyp) => {
            if (prev[currTyp] === undefined) {
                prev[currTyp] = []
                prev[currTyp].push({'produkt': curr.produkt, 'ilosc': curr.ilosc})
            }
            else {
                prev[currTyp].push({'produkt': curr.produkt, 'ilosc': curr.ilosc})

            }
            return prev
        }, 0)
    }
    else {
        if (prev[curr.typ] === undefined) {
            prev[curr.typ] = []
            prev[curr.typ].push({'produkt': curr.produkt, 'ilosc': curr.ilosc})

        }
        else {
            prev[curr.typ].push({'produkt': curr.produkt, 'ilosc': curr.ilosc})

        }
        return prev
    }

    }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I should've written last
`return prev` below the `}`, but could you explain me why does it have to be below that?